# Sync folder automatically upload files?

Tags: ubuntu-one

After I sync a folder I will have to upload each file in that folder, or Ubuntu One will upload all of them for me? I am not sure of how it really works.

Answer (score 2):

Syncing the folder will be enough for all the files in the folder to upload.

Comment: Why? That shouldn't be necessary. If you disconnect while it's being synced, then the sync will just resume when you reconnect.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Of course. I added that because it seemed important to the OP to get all the files uploaded. Will remove it for clarity.